# www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id Only giving last 15 videos

Tags: youtube, feed, youtube-data-api

I want to get last 50 videos from www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id, Currently I can only retrieve last 15 videos. I have tried max-result parameter, but it failed.

Comment: It is `&max-results=<integer>` and not `&max-result=<integer>`

Comment: Hi @C0dekid , Thanks for the reply, I have tried that too.. but it is not working, any idea?

Comment: Maybe youtube limited it to 15 videos then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of above method I have found another way to fetch youtube playlist videos, here it is

```
<?php
$playlistId = 'Playlist Id here';
$maxResults = 50;
$apiKey = 'youtube api key here';

$string = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='.$playlistId.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$apiKey.''));

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($string);

foreach($string->items as $item) {
$video_id = $item->snippet->resourceId->videoId;
}
?>
```

Comment: I have just started messing around with the API myself. I have noticed that there are several things missing from the API that the XML datafeed had. Example: starRating, Statistics, and a few other items. Do you know perhaps, how to get these with the API?

Comment: @WayneBarron , Please check below codes which I found here
( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581215/get-video-ratings-with-youtube-api-v3-php)

Comment: Thanks Ashkar. It is PHP, I know very little about PHP. I am slowly working my way towards getting the vb.net working right now with help from another forum. What I will have to do, is first get a list of all videoId's and then process each videoId to get the its information. A slow process. But hopefully when it is all said and done. It will do it FAST. That is what I am hoping for, anyway.